# Synchronize vehicle signals at a same sample frequency (in Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, synchronization, can-bus

I'm working with many CAN-bus data collected on a vehicle.
For example, we have speed, acceleration, and GPS data.
*Data is time-stamped*.

However, the data was not collected at the same frequency.
For example, accelerations are sampled at 5ms and speeds at 20ms. *So their timestamps match sometimes (but very little)* and do not start at the same time.

***I want to synchronize these data by resampling them to be at the same frequency*** (e.g. 20ms), minimizing the loss of information.
I'm thinking about using a **linear interpolation**.
However, would you have another approach that might be more interesting?

Thank you !

P.S : I use the **Python** language.

EDIT :

for acceleration data (timestamps, value) :

```
[(1533646242104248, 0.20000000000004547),
 (1533646242110138, 0.2400000000000091),
 (1533646242114266, 0.37999999999999545),
 (1533646242119157, 0.4199999999999591),
 (1533646242124221, 0.32000000000005),
 (1533646242130199, 0.17999999999994998),
 (1533646242135142, 0.2400000000000091),
 (1533646242139214, 0.37999999999999545),
 (1533646242144234, 0.37999999999999545),
 (1533646242149544, 0.2799999999999727),
 (1533646242154575, 0.2400000000000091),
 (1533646242160464, 0.32000000000005),
 (1533646242164268, 0.37999999999999545),
...]
```

For Speed data (timestamps, value):

```
[(1533646241965185, 0.0),
 (1533646241985104, 0.0),
 (1533646242004771, 0.0),
 (1533646242024239, 0.0),
 (1533646242045494, 0.0),
 (1533646242065128, 0.0),
 (1533646242085139, 0.0),
 (1533646242104248, 0.0),
 (1533646242124221, 0.0),
 (1533646242144234, 0.0),
 (1533646242164268, 0.0),
 (1533646242185832, 0.0),
 (1533646242205172, 0.0),
 (1533646242224951, 0.0),
 (1533646242245573, 0.0),
 (1533646242265142, 0.0),
 (1533646242284591, 0.0),
 (1533646242304243, 0.0),
 (1533646242325596, 0.0),
 (1533646242344589, 0.0),
 (1533646242364254, 0.0),
 (1533646243164268, 0.0),
 (1533646243184546, 0.0),
 (1533646243204298, 0.0),
 (1533646243224661, 0.0),
 ...]
```

For speed, values at 0 are Normal because it's the start of driving (so, that changes later)

Initially, these data were in Json File, so I extracted them and I merged (OUTER) them in one pandas dataframe, but, of course, many NaNs values have been added. But I do not like this approach. This is why ***I want to synchronize/resample before merge***.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you share a sample of your data (or something that looks like it). It'll be easier to help you.

Comment: Hello @SergedeGossondeVarennes, sure, I edited my post and added a sample of data. You should see it now.